# Writing a program to divide user_num by x 3 times

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program for my class that divides the user_num by x three times. Thus far, I have:

```
user_num = input()
x = input()
```

So what is the missing link to do this? By three times, it should be like if the user inputs:

```
2000
2
```

Then the output should be:

```
1000 500 250
```

Am I on the right track and if so, what is the next step to make this work?

Comment: What have you actually attempted, other than reading two strings?

Comment: Nothing quite yet except defining my two inputs. I am very new to this type of thing. Like I love it I just get confused.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is simply what you have, except the numbers are also converted into a numeric type to allow for mathematical operations.

```
user_num = int(input("enter a number: "))
x = int(input("enter x: "))
```

After that, you want to divide `user_num` by `x`, and then print the result, three times over. This is done using a loop. `//` will perform the division and ignore the decimal. `print` will work as expected, and the `end` argument will format the output as you described.

```
for _ in range(3):
  user_num = user_num // x
  print(user_num, end=" ")
```